# What is the most idiomatic way to "delay" the construction of a C++ object?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

For built-in types, like int, you can delay the initialization simply writing nothing. Is there a way to do the same for C++ objects?

I wrote this code that does the job, but I was wondering if there is an idiomatic way. If so, what is it? Was it even possible before the introduction of aligned storage?

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct delayed {
    delayed() { unset_init(); }
    template <typename...Args> void init(Args&&... args) {
        new ( memory() ) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        set_init();
    }

    operator T*() {
        return memory();
    }

    ~delayed() {
        if (get_init()) {
            memory()->~T();
            unset_init();
        }
    }

private:
    T* memory() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&bytes_); }
    unsigned char* raw_memory() { return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&bytes_); }

    unsigned char& init() { return *( raw_memory() + sizeof(T) ); }
    bool get_init() { return init() != 0; }
    void set_init() { init() = 1; }
    void unset_init() { init() = 0; }

    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T) + 1, alignof(T)>::type bytes_{};
};
```

Comment: I really believe you should add that "built" flag check in the destructor... Specially if you're concerned with it being idiomatic and all that. As a bonus, I would enforce `init` to be called if the address is requested and the object has not been built.

Comment: Basically, your code is pretty fundamentally unsafe.  All paths to the destructor must have initialized the object, including all stack unwinding.  Did you audit all of your code to make sure nothing at all throws?

Comment: Actually, I am aware of that as I wrote in the end.The example is just a quick hack against the stackoverflow tendency of not-answering, but asking "what did you try?"

Comment: `For built-in types, like int, you can delay the initialization simply writing nothing` But that's not what happens at all. You **default-initialise** using the default constructor, which for basic types does nothing and leaves the value invalid - and delay **assignment**, which then makes the object valid. The difference is crucial. But to be fair, I guess the unfortunately named concept of "uninitialised variable" doesn't help.

Answer (score 23):

In C++17 and later I expect the preferred idiom will be `std::optional<T>`. In C++11 and C++14 it seems that `std::unique_ptr<T>` is common though it has the obvious drawback of requiring a heap allocation.

Usage:

```
std::optional<T> t; // initially empty
// do some stuff
// now we're ready to create the T value
t.emplace(foo, bar); // constructs the T with foo, bar as args
```

Comment: You could always use a placement new into a char buffer of the right size when creating the unique_ptr.

Comment: @ZanLynx: And then you have to use a deleter that only calls the destructor, rather than the default one that calls `delete`.

Comment: `std::optional<T>` doesn't delay construction. But you can move-assign into it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Doesn't it? cppreference says the constructor with no arguments "Constructs the object that _does not contain a value_."

Comment: @underscore_d: I'm not sure of the original context here: the "but you can move-assign into it" refers to the Boost documentation's example of using the `boost::optional`'s default constructor. Much of the point was that I asked for an example of that to be included, that is, at that point there was no example. That comment has been removed by the mods, always changing history... Brian then included the example of move assignment. Then Nicol Bolas suggested `emplace`, and the answer's example was updated. I was unaware of `emplace`, which indeed is direct delayed construction.

Comment: FWIW there's no reason not to use the `std::optional` code in your C++11 projects right now afaict: https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional

Answer (score 6):

First, an `int` variable is a C++ object. Presumably when you talk about C++ objects as opposed to `int`, you mean *class type objects*. But not just class type objects, because you can do this:

```
struct Blah{ int x; int y; };

auto main() -> int
{
    Blah o;    // Uninitialized, indeterminate value.
    // Whatever
    o = {6, 7};
};
```

So probably you mean *object of a class type with at least one user-defined constructor*.

The most common ways to delay initialization of such an object, relative to the declaration of something used to access it, include

- `std::vector` as an expanding array,
- direct dynamic allocation (regardless of how the lifetime is managed), and
- refactoring the code,

… where the refactoring essentially is about moving later usage code to a function or functions.

For example, the ugly and inefficient delayed-initialization code

```
unique_ptr<MyClass> p;

if( condition() )
{
    // Some code here, then
    p.reset( new MyDerivedA( 123 ) );
}
else
{
    // Some code here, then
    p.reset( new MyDerivedB( "andromeda" ) );
}
// Code using *p here.
```

… might be refactored as

```
void foo( MyClass&& o )
{
    // Code using o here.
}

…
if( condition() )
{
    // Some code here, then
    foo( MyDerivedA( 123 ) );
}
else
{
    // Some code here, then
    foo( MyDerivedB( "andromeda" ) );
}
```

Less common ways include

- placement `new` in some suitably aligned byte array, like in your code, and
- if your class is movable, using an `Optional_` class (Barton-Nackman `Fallible`, Boost and C++17 `optional`) that supports move assignment.

Whether these techniques can be regarded as idiomatic for the purpose of delaying initialization, is, I think, quite subjective, personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about an *idiomatic way* of doing that.
The other answers are quite interesting indeed (`std::optional` is to become part of the standard library, but can it be considered *idiomatic*?).
Here is one more example of a delayed initialization based on another idiom, the *pimpl* (minimal, working example):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct I {
    void doSomething(int i) { val = i; }
    int getSomeData() { return val; }
    int val;
};

class C {
    static I& initialized(C &c) {
        std::cout << "is initialized" << std::endl;
        return *(c.impl);
    }

    static I& uninitialized(C &c) {
        std::cout << "was uninitialized" << std::endl;
        c.impl = std::make_unique<I>();
        c.getter = &initialized;
        return c.getter(c);
    }

public:
    C(): impl{nullptr}, getter{&uninitialized} {}

    void doSomething(int i) { getter(*this).doSomething(i); }
    int getSomeData() { return getter(*this).getSomeData(); }

private:
    using Getter = I&(*)(C &);
    std::unique_ptr<I> impl;
    Getter getter;
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.doSomething(42);
    c.getSomeData();
}
```

In this case, the class is nothing more than a wrapper for a bunch of data and functions contained in another class.
By delaying the construction of the internal representation, you are actually delaying the initialization of the outer class.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with a potential copy or move instead of directly initializing you could use a union. I would prefer an `optional`, either from `std::experimental`, C++17 or e.g. Boost.

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    S(int, float) {std::cout << "S::S()" << std::endl;}
    ~S() {std::cout << "S::~S()" << std::endl;}
};

template<typename T>
union Delayed {
    bool initialized;
    T obj;

    Delayed(): initialized(false) {}
    ~Delayed() {}
};

int main() {
    Delayed<S> d;

    std::cout << 1 <<std::endl;

    d.obj = S(1, 1.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that in general the assignment here is Undefined Behavior. E.g. assignment of a `std::string` will in general try to deallocate the target's buffer, but its internal pointer value, as an uninitialized union member, is indeterminate, garbage. But you can take charge of assignment by putting the union definition inside a class. The union members can then be treated as members of the class.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's definitely not good to think the `string` member here can be treated as a valid living object later. Do you mean to put such `union`s in a `struct` with a 'type' `enum`, and deal with 'active member' changes conditionally? Separately, `union`s can have assignment operators, but those are no more useful than those of the contained types if their life state is unknown.

Comment: @underscore_d: Yes, we're talking discriminated union here, probably the minimum with a boolean empty/non-empty as discriminator.